# OrientDB - How can I create database on a clustering servers?

Tags: distributed, orientdb

I setup two nodes with the default configuration, cluster status:

```
"members": [{
    "id": "192.168.1.101:2434",
    "listeners": [{"protocol": "ONetworkProtocolBinary", "listen": "192.168.1.101:2424"}, {"protocol": "ONetworkProtocolHttpDb", "li
80"}],
    "alias": "192.168.1.101:2434",
    "status": "aligning"
    }, {
    "id": "192.168.1.102:2435",
    "listeners": [{"protocol": "ONetworkProtocolBinary", "listen": "192.168.1.101:2425"}, {"protocol": "ONetworkProtocolHttpDb", "li
80"}],
    "alias": "192.168.1.101:2435",
    "status": "aligning"
    }],
"name": "_hzInstance_1_orientdb",
"local": "192.168.1.101:2435"
}
```

but when I use Java API to connect to one server, and tried to create a database, exception occurs,

```
admin = new OServerAdmin(PATH);
            admin.connect("root", "password");

            if (!admin.existsDatabase()) {
                admin.createDatabase("document", "local");
            }
```

stack:

```
Cannot create the remote storage: demo1
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Cannot create database
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinary.createException(OChannelBinary.java:515)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinary.handleStatus(OChannelBinary.java:470)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynch.beginResponse(OChannelBinaryAsynch.java:145)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynch.beginResponse(OChannelBinaryAsynch.java:59)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.beginResponse(OStorageRemote.java:1832)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.getResponse(OStorageRemote.java:1863)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OServerAdmin.createDatabase(OServerAdmin.java:184)
    at com.test.db.Client.main(Client.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinary.createException(OChannelBinary.java:517)
    ... 7 more
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot create the remote storage: demo1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager.error(OLogManager.java:119)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OServerAdmin.createDatabase(OServerAdmin.java:189)
    at com.test.db.Client.main(Client.java:19)
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Cannot create database
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinary.createException(OChannelBinary.java:515)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinary.handleStatus(OChannelBinary.java:470)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynch.beginResponse(OChannelBinaryAsynch.java:145)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynch.beginResponse(OChannelBinaryAsynch.java:59)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.beginResponse(OStorageRemote.java:1832)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.getResponse(OStorageRemote.java:1863)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OServerAdmin.createDatabase(OServerAdmin.java:184)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinary.createException(OChannelBinary.java:517)
    ... 7 more
```

Why this happen? How can I craete database on a clustering servers?

THX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial creation of database must be done outside the cluster. Then copy the database to all the servers and startup the cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I need to start a server on my local machine, create the database, and then copy to 201 and 204, and restart 201,204. Is there any document for these operations?

Comment: We're updating the documentation about the new stuff on clustering. However it's just a copy of the directory.

Comment: Sounds like a hack, the `distributed-config.json` gets already copied. After restarting the second node in my 2-node cluster, the other database-files gets fetched automatically. Seems like there is only the last step missing to automate this completely.

Comment: We support also auto-deploy: just start a new server in cluster and the database will be copied to the new one. With huge database this could be very slow, and a manual copy could be preferable.